# Javascript Comparing a value.length to equal a certain amount of characters

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out how to make a variable equal a certain length of characters. As I am trying to create form validation through Javascript.
However, it doesnt seem to be working.
The section that doesnt seem to be validating is the final elseif statement where I am comparing the length of a master, visa and american card, hhowever' it is letting me put any amount of characters in.

I have tried change the symbols being used, however, i feel !== is the right thing to be doing.

```
function orderValidate() { //need to work on this
    //validate contact number to only be numbers\
    var american = document.getElementById("americanInput").value;
    var master = document.getElementById("masterInput").value;
    var visa = document.getElementById("visaInput").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var errMsg = document.getElementById("errMsg");
    var numberRegex = /^\d{10}$/;
    var emailRegex = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
    var contactNumber = document.getElementById("number").value;
    if (contactNumber.length < 8 || (!contactNumber.match(numberRegex))) {
        errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid phone number";
        return false;
    } else if (email.length < 7 || !email.match(emailRegex)) {
        errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email";
        return false;
    } else if (master.length !== 16|| visa.length !== 16 || american.length 
    !== 15){
        errMsg.innerHTML = "Please check your card details again";
        return false;
    }

    }
```

```
        <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="card" id="visaInput">
        <input type="text" name="card" id="masterInput">
        <input type="text" name="card" id="americanInput">
        </div>
```

```
function showAmerican() {
    document.getElementById("americanInput").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("masterInput").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("visaInput").style.display = 'none';
}

function showVisa() {
    document.getElementById("visaInput").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("americanInput").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("masterInput").style.display = 'none';
}

function showMastercard() {
    document.getElementById("masterInput").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("americanInput").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("visaInput").style.display = 'none';
}
```

```
    master.onclick = showMastercard;
    american.onclick = showAmerican;
    repeat.onclick = repeatAddress;
```

The form instead of validating just sends it straight through once it reaches to this stage...

Comment: you should validate it step by step. what i mean, you should try to validate number first then next and then next. If all works fine then compose them

Comment: Oh my bad, I forgot to be specific. It fails at the  else if (master.length !== 16|| visa.length !== 16 || american.length 
    !== 15){ section

Comment: Hint: Does a user filling the form enter details of one card or all the cards? How can you check only the card entered?

Comment: Only one card is being checked, hence the OR statement. I have added to the article to show how I show these functions depending on what is clicked

Comment: If I entered a value in `master` card field, what do you think would be the values of `american` and `visa` when that last condition is reached during form evaluation?

Comment: That's a good point as it would still be submitting that information, however I am just trying to do one step of validation at a time. How would you suggest doing what you mentioned?

Comment: Check out my answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are checking the card length of all available cards even when they are not entered. You should only check the length of entered card.

```
if (master.length !== 16|| visa.length !== 16 || american.length !== 15) {}
```

The above condition would be true all the time. This is because when form is submitted, only one card is entered and form fields of other cards would be empty. Then their length would be `0` and wouldn't be equal to `15` or `16`, which makes this condition to be true all the time.

```
if (master.length > 0 && master.length !== 16 || 
  visa.length > 0 && visa.length !== 16 ||
  american.length > 0 && american.length !== 15) {}
```

Changing the condition as shown above would check if a card field is entered and only then it would evaluate if it matches the required length.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("americanInput").value` is a string. 
 Try

- `parseInt(document.getElementById("americanInput").value)` or
- `+document.getElementById("americanInput").value` which converts the operand into a number

Comment: That is why I have used the .length as that turns it into a integer doesn't it? as I am checking the length of characters for the value and checking against the number 16, or 15.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Then it should ideally work, unless your value is an integer for some reason and doing .length on a number returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

Also instead of creating separate function for all, you can create one function, for example showCard and pass the parameter like AMEX, VISA, Master
Example

```
showCard(cardName) {
//functionBody
}
```

And then call the function

```
showCard('American');
showCard('Visa');
```

This will optimize your code :)
Cheers

Comment: I am not sure how passing parameters work in Javascript. 
Would it go like function showCard(cardName) {
if (cardName == "American) {
do something? or does that cardName parameter need to be defined later on with , var cardName?

Comment: Correct , you need to apply condition inside function.

Comment: I will try to run the code on JSfiddle , will reply back in sometime